# VBA: compare every row of two columns then cut the matching row and paste it elsewhere

Tags: excel, vba

I have this table:

A  B  C

4  4  X

4  1

4  0  X

4  8

4  4

4  9 X

I need to find matching cells in the row from columns A and B and then cut that matching row and paste it below the table. The range of data is A2:C8.

In my table there are 2 matches, so the result should look like this:

4       4                   X
4       4

Here is my code:

```
Sub cutter()

Dim cell1 As Integer, cell2 As Integer

cell1 = Range("A2").Value
cell2 = Range("B2").Value

If cell1 = cell2 Then
Sheet1.Range("A2:C2").Cut Sheet1.Range("A27:C27")
End If

End Sub
```

It works fine but I need to compare every row. 
I know that I should implement loop like here:

```
Dim rng As Range
Dim row As Range
Dim cell As Range
Set rng = Range("A2:C8")
For Each row In rng.Rows
  For Each cell In row.Cells
' condition
    Next cell
Next row
```

But I don't know how :(

Help anyone?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code loops until the first empty row in A:

```
Sub testcompare()
i = 1 'start in cell 1
j = 27 'cut start in cell 27

While Not IsEmpty(Cells(i, 1))
If Cells(i, 1).Value = Cells(i, 2).Value Then
Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 3)).Cut Range(Cells(j, 1), Cells(j, 3))
i = i + 1
j = j + 1
Else
i = i + 1
End If
Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: Really appreciate your help, thank you. The solution works great! But with a large ranges it's maybe not a very optimal solution... that was just an example table, I will work with range of cells A2:C2202. Anyway, thanks a lot!